# How to create custom HTML codes generator with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create HTML code generator for some html code with some var using javascript or jquery. so it will be a static web page

for example, this my html code

```
<a href="home.html">Link name</a>
```

so if the user put his Link name in input form the result code in textarea will apear according to this inputs.

so if i input mido the result will be

```
<a href="home.html">mido</a>
```

if there is jquery plugin will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it by hand using events. There is a [jsFiddle up here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4WvW/).

```
Input your link name: <input onchange="document.getElementById('changed_link').innerText = this.value" />
<br /> <a id="changed_link" href="home.html"></a>
```

If you wish for it to be instantaneous, replace [onchange with onkeyup](http://jsfiddle.net/V6KPz/).